I want to install 64 GB Ram in Supermicro SYS-2028GR-THRT for AI and ML. Can in opt for 4DRx4 Rank instead of 4Rx4 Rank? If I cannot why? Cautions?
This table is from the Motherboard (X10DRG-HT) manual
I want to install 8 sticks now and add the remaining 8 later because of budget. I am thinking of going with the configuration in second last row in the table.
Can you guys tell me wheather 4DRx4 and 4Rx4 ranks the same or not. My intuition says it is the same. 4DRx4 is dual die(I don't what that exacly means). I think I can use 4DRx4 as the same way as 4Rx4.But I am not sure. That's why I am asking.
If I am in the wrong forum.Please let me know where should I ask this question.
the detailed Specs of the server can be found here
Any kind of advice are welcome.I am a complete Beginner Thankyou
